# ReactJS production build excluding files

Tags: php, reactjs

I'm new to ReactJS and just finished my first project.

One of my components is a contact form that uses with a PHP file to send an email.
On dev build, it works fine on localhost.

But as soon as I replace the localhost path to the PHP file to direct link and create a production build, I get a 404 for the PHP file.

Here is my folder structure

[image]

And my link to contact.php from Contact component looks like `const API_PATH = '/api/contact/contact.php';`

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure is `http` and not `https`?

Comment: @JoseRojas super sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by moving the API folder into the production build folder.

I'm not sure if it's the right way to do things but it worked.

Comment: If you're using the API code in react it needs to live inside your `src` folder somewhere. If you're only calling it via javascript at run time then put it in your `public` folder. Everything from `public` is copied to your build folder at build time.